# discrete line spectrum in latex

Tags: pdf, line

[image]I am trying to make this line spectrum. I found a code of this type but the tilde sign does not recognized in my latex environment. I have most updated version of latex

```
\tikzset{
  % define the bar graph element
  bar/.pic={
    \fill (-.1,0) rectangle (.1,#1) (0,#1) node[above,scale=1/2]{$#1$};
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=4cm]
    \draw
      % the main axis
      (-3,0) edge[-latex] (3,0)
      % draw the distribution and label it
      foreach[count=\i from -2] ~ in {1/16,4/16,6/16,4/16,1/16}{
        (\i,0) pic[red]{bar=~} node[below]{$\i$}
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me, but why using `~` as variable name and not adhere to standard syntax using something like `\x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code proposed is not executable and not complete. I have made some changes to have visibles results like this (You can delete the grid and the left scale):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{
    % define the bar graph element
    bar/.pic={
        \fill (-.1,0) rectangle (.1,#1) (0,#1) node[above]{\bfseries $#1$};
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=10cm,scale=2]
        \draw[gray!20] (-3,-.1) grid (3,.3);
        \foreach \i in {-0.1,0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3} \draw (-3.1,\i) node[left] () {$\i$}; 
        \draw
        % the main axis
        (-3,0) edge[-latex] (3,0)
        % draw the distribution and label it
        foreach[count=\i from -2] ~ in {1/16,4/16,6/16,4/16,1/16}{
            (\i,0) pic[red]{bar=~} node[below]{\Large $\i$}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Raffaele Santoro. Please i am not still able to fix the no volume sticks…

Comment: @SophiaN. I am sorry. The picture You posted NOW dont have any relation with the code posted BEFORE. So if You have a new question You are welcomed. But please to be very clear.

Comment: @SophiaN. More: in the code proposed now You dont have the data to plot correctly the graph You posted now. Please be more accurate and complete.

Answer (score 2):

According to given data for "bars" in the "yticks + bars" loop in your MWE, your diagram is not correct. It should be something like this:

[image]

MWE, where I instead of your `\pic`s use simple lines width width of 3mm (consequently code is simpler and more clear than yours), is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!20] (-3,-1) grid (3,5);
% x-axis
\draw[-Straight Barb] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
% xticks
\foreach \i in {-0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5} \node[left] at (-3,10*\i) {$\i$};
% yticks + bars
\foreach \i [count=\j from -2] in {1/16,4/16,6/16,4/16,1/16}
       \draw[red, line width=3mm]   (\j,0)  node[below, text=black] {$\j$} -- ++ (0,10*\i) 
                                            node[very thin, above, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt] {$\i$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was trying actually to make the figure above. The most relevant code I found ( even though it was not what I wanted) did not work. I mean it was not my code but it was close enough what I wanted. Thank you so much for modifying the code. I want to make bars with “no” volume specifically

Comment: @SophiaN., please not edit my answer, your desired image move to your question. Even better would be, if you would extend your `\foreach` loop with actual data.

Comment: Sorry @Zarko. I am new user therefore accidents of this type happens. Still I am not able to see how to make "no" volume sticks. That is a periodic trig function with spectrum being discrete. Means I have no data handy, instead I might use my common sense to come up with different amplitudes.